# Change 1st instance of every unique row as 1 in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hi let us assume i have a data frame

```
      Name quantity
0      a    0
1      a    0
2      b    0
3      b    0
4      c    0
```

And i want something like

```
   Name quantity
0      a    1
1      a    0
2      b    1
3      b    0
4      c    1
```

which is essentially i want to change first row of every unique element with one

currently i am using code like:

```
def store_counter(df):
        unique_names = list(df.name.unique())
        df['quantity'] = 0
        for i,j in df.iterrows():
            if j['name'] in unique_outlets:
                df.loc[i, 'quantity'] = 1
                unique_names.remove(j['name'])
            else:
                pass
        return df
```

which is highly inefficient. is there a better approach for this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[~df.Name.duplicated(), 'quantity'] = 1
print (df)
  Name  quantity
0    a         1
1    a         0
2    b         1
3    b         0
4    c         1
```

If need set both values use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['quantity'] = np.where(df.Name.duplicated(), 0, 1)
print (df)
  Name  quantity
0    a         1
1    a         0
2    b         1
3    b         0
4    c         1
```